# how to use foreach with an IEnumerable<String>

Tags: c#, string, ienumerable

```
System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<String> lines = File.ReadLines("C:\\Rooms.txt");
Console.WriteLine(lines.Count());
MessageBox.Show(lines.Count().ToString());
foreach(var line in lines)
{
    // ERROR ON THIS LINE THE NAMESPACE NAME LINE COULD NOT BE FOUND
}
```

I want to get the content of lines and display in a MessageBox.
However I get an error on the foreach

Thanks for the assist.

Comment: It's just a typo - you've not given the variable a type: `foreach(string line in lines)`

Comment: foreach (var line in lines)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give the loop variable a type, so change

```
foreach(line in lines)
```

to

```
foreach(string line in lines)
```

Apart from that you will get another exception:

> ObjectDisposedException : {"Cannot read from a closed TextReader."}

[`File.ReadLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) does not return a collection, it is similar like a `StreamReader`, it allows to read the file without reading all into memory first. But it needs an open stream. Once you have "executed" it it is disposed.

So you either have to use [`File.ReadAllLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1.aspx) which returns a `string[]` or don't use it twice.

1. `Count()`
2. `foreach(line in lines)`

From MSDN:

> The `ReadLines` and `ReadAllLines` methods differ as follows: When you use
>   ReadLines, you can start enumerating the collection of strings before
>   the whole collection is returned; when you use ReadAllLines, you must
>   wait for the whole array of strings be returned before you can access
>   the array. Therefore, when you are working with very large files,
>   ReadLines can be more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

[`foreach`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6.aspx) requires you to specify the type and name of the variable. You only specified `line`, which it took to be the type. `var`, which implicitly types the variable, is [the suggested convention](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff926074.aspx):

```
foreach (var line in lines) {
```

Comment: *Use implicit typing for local variables when the type of the variable is obvious from the right side of the assignment* - `lines` could be anything.

Comment: @RGraham There's also "Use implicit typing to determine the type of the loop variable in for and foreach loops." with the example `foreach (var ch in laugh)`. I take this to mean that the "when it's obvious" line does not apply to `for`/`foreach` variables. In some cases, I'd agree with your suggestion, but I think `lines` is obvious enough.

Comment: Good point Tim, I didn't see that until after I had left my comment.